# get most discussed forums in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, orm

I got two classes: `Forum` and `Topic`. `Forum` has_many `Topic`s.

1. How do you get the (lets suppose) 5 most disscused forums?
2. How do you limit it by Date? for example, most disscused this day/week etc.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. How do you get the (lets suppose) 5 most disscused forums?**

You will probably be able to do something like this:

```
Forum.where('id IN (?)', Topic.limit(5).count(:group => 'forum_id').map {|key, value| key })
```

**2. How do you limit it by Date? for example, most disscused this day/week etc.**

```
Forum.where('id IN (?)', Topic.where('date > ', 1.week.ago.to_s(:db)).limit(5).count(:group => 'forum_id').map {|key, value| key })
```

Answer (score 2):

If the most discussed forum is the one with the most topics, the query would be:

```
Forum.joins(:topics).group("forums.id").order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(5)
```

The five forums with the largest number of opened topics in the last week:

```
Forum.joins(:topics)
     .where("topics.created_at > ?", 1.week.ago)
     .group("forums.id")
     .order("COUNT(*) DESC")
     .limit(5)
```

Comment: This is actually better than my way, it only fires one query.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to keep timestamps (created_at and updated_at) in both tables. And update them whenever some activity occurs on the topic.

Steps:

1. Keep `timestamps` in both the tables.
2. Add an `after_save` callback
   in `Topic` model, to update `updated_at` of the parent forum.
3. Get the list of forums `order by updated_at desc`.

---

```
class Topic
 def after_save
   self.forum.touch
 end
end
```

---

Then run a query like 
`Forum.order("updated_at desc").limit(5)`

Comment: That doesn't give you the most discussed forums, but the most recently discussed forums.